# Rigidbody.MovePosition() behaving strangely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    private Animator animator;

    public float speed = 5f;
    void Start() {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Get player input based on world space.
        float playerHorizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float playerVerticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        //Get camera-normalized directional vectors
        Vector3 forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        Vector3 right = Camera.main.transform.right;

        //Create direction-relative input vectors
        Vector3 forwardRelativeVerticalInput = playerVerticalInput * forward;
        Vector3 rightRelativeHorizontalInput = playerHorizontalInput * right;


        Vector3 cameraRelativeMovement = forwardRelativeVerticalInput + rightRelativeHorizontalInput;

        Vector3 movement = cameraRelativeMovement * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);


        transform.forward = cameraRelativeMovement;


        if (cameraRelativeMovement != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", true);
        }
        else {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
        }
    }
}
```

I know similar questions have been posted before but I haven't been able to find a solution to what I'm experiencing.

I have the code above and it is linked to a character with a rigidbody component and 'is kinematic' checked. When I try to move, the character doesn't move for ages and then randomly jumps forward a random distance and doesn't do it again until I hit W again.

This has worked before when I used `transform.Translate` but obviously my character ran through the floor when the camera pointed down so I was trying to fix the issue.

Comment: I would check for how many frames `rb.MovePosition` is being called. You expect its being called for just the frame when the key is pressed, but maybe there is something more going on. Also I'd recomend to use the call to `rb.Moveposition` in the `FixedUpdate` as in the documentation (example)[https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html]

Comment: I removed the animator part of your code and added it to a sphere, it worked fine

Comment: LIke rusty says above it is your update method.  You are only seeing motion every time update is run.  If you update more often then movement will be smoother.

Comment: Thanks everyone but the update method was definitely being called multiple times as the animation was working exactly as it should, it's just the movement I was having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I notice about your code. You said this method used to work with `transform.translate` but not anymore, this tells me that your movement vectors are probably fine up until the point you changed them for this implementation (my guess is everything is the same except when you added `tranform.position` to your vector, since the function doesn't take speed, it takes position). You could try testing `tranform.position + movement` or just `movement` with a `Debug.Log()` statement, but that's probably not your issue.

Since you said this issue only started when you changed the function you use to move the player, I would try just inputting a non-changing Vector3 into the movement function: `rb.movePosition(tranform.position + new Vector3(1,0,0));` or something like that, just to see if the movement function is even working.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is the movement vector that's issue so I'm trying to debug it at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, earlier when I tested it, the character only moved when 'is kinematic' wasn't checked so I think the movement was just caused by built in physics. I've now checked it again and the character still doesn't move, even with Vector3(1, 0, 0) instead of movement

Comment: that's really weird. Although it may not be optimal, if you just want a quick fix, you might be able to solve it by using `Rigidbody.velocity()` instead of `movePostition`, or just switching from rigidbody based movement to the built in Character Controller component (check out [Brakeys youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE) for a great tutorial on this).

Comment: sorry this only just caught my eye after i posted my first comment, but when you say "even with Vector3(1, 0, 0) instead of movement", you should be using `new Vector3(1, 0, 0)`. If you don't add `new` you'll run into issues.

Comment: I think I was being really dumb here… I had both a character controller and a rigidbody on my character. Do you think issue could have been that? I’m really sorry, I’m just really new to unity and it’s not the most intuitive thing.

Comment: probably not the issue, you could try disabling the component ("uncheck" it) and see if things work. No worries, we all started somewhere.